# Is it possible to run asp code on htm files?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, asp-classic, iis-7.5

I have an old website with thousands of static html files (running on IIS7).
Is there ANY way to enable running asp or asp.net code on these files?

I need this for various reasons starting with 301 redirecting some old pages to new ones and more...

---

Additional Info:
The htm files or old. I need to 301 redirect. I tried adding a wild card in order to have them go through the asp parser but with no luck. Also tried handling them in the Global.asax (url routing) but also with no luck...

Maybe I'm doing it wrong but there has to be a solution. I am quite certain there is a way with wildcard to get them to run through the asp but don't know how and my hosting company doesn't know also.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it is, if you declare the html extention to pass from the asp.net - but I did not have try that.

Comment: Exactly what do you want to do? You have .html files which do what? And you want to add code that does what? Please tell us.

Comment: If this is primarily about page redirection, are you aware of IIS7'x URL Rewrite/redirect module http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module

Answer (score 3):

You can map the .htm or .html extension to asp.dll through Handler Mappings in IIS manager, (so that .htm/.html files become Classic ASP files).  Just look at the setting which is already there for .asp and duplicate it for .htm

(I've done this before a couple of times.  On both occasions a site had been moved from Apache to IIS and most of the .htm files used Server Side Includes, which Classic ASP supports)